# PHP Header Location Not Redirecting to HTML File

Tags: php, html, forms, header, location

I am running the following log-in script for my application. On my own home server the redirect always worked after a successful log-in and took the user to their Private page. Since uploading the application to GoDaddy it no longer redirects.

```
    <?php

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
    require("common.php");

    // This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the
    // login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here
    // to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form.
    $submitted_username = '';

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted
    // If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        // This query retreives the user's information from the database using
        // their username.
        $query = "
            SELECT
                id,
                username,
                password,
                salt,
                email,
                reg_type,
                assoc
            FROM users
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";

        // The parameter values
        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username']
        );

        try
        {
            // Execute the query against the database
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

        // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not.
        // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not.
        // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true.
        $login_ok = false;

        // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username
        // they entered is not registered.
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row)
        {
            // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database,
            // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password
            // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database.
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']);
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
            {
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
            }

            if($check_password === $row['password'])
            {
                // If they do, then we flip this to true
                $login_ok = true;
            }
        }

        // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page
        // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again
        if($login_ok)
        {
            // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by
            // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is
            // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values
            // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these
            // sensitive values first.
            unset($row['salt']);
            unset($row['password']);

            // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'.
            // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether
            // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve
            // the user's details.
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;

            // Redirect the user to the private members-only page.
            header('Location: ../private.html');
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            // Tell the user they failed
            print("Login Failed.");

            // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new
            // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should
            // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them
            // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information:
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
    }
?>
```

Can I get some advice on how to get the Header command to work?

Comment: Make sure your script isn't generating any output (errors, warnings, notices) before you call the header() function.

Comment: Completely off topic, but relevant: You might want to consider using the built in pbkdf2 function in php for hashing. Since it's almost the same as what you're doing there, but safer/easier. http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. As said; you may be outputting before header.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini issue: output_buffering = On
may be open.

Please controls header.

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Location: ../private.html');
    exit;
}else{
   echo 'header problems';
}
```

Comment: if($login_ok) current true ? please control.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfact & you also redirect page using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = url; or
window.location = url; or
location.replace(url);
</script>
```